# Format number from (-/+)xx.xxxxxxxxx to xxxx.xxxx in PHP

Tags: php

i need to arrange a number to a format like this `xxxx.xxxx`. But I get as input something like this `(-/+)xx.xxxxxxxxx`.

If the number is `x.xx` it should get the above mentioned format by adding `0s` to end and front.

please guide me on the correct way to get this done!

Comment: See `number_format` function.

Comment: at least try *something* before asking

Comment: @Dagon sry i tried some..this is converting GPS data into a standard message for a specific need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `explode` & `str_pad` -

```
$num = 7.89;

$temp = explode('.', $num);

echo str_pad($temp[0], 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT).'.'.str_pad($temp[1], 4, 0, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```

**Output**

```
0007.8900
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sprintf("%f4.6");
The number before the dot would determine de number of digits fot the integer part and de other, the number of decimals